# Quero aumentar o envio (tempo) para upload de arquivos

Tags: php

Tenho um script que funciona muito bem, que faz o upload múltiplo de imagens e ainda insere marca d'água.

A questão é a seguinte: No servidor, consigo colocar 300s no MAX_EXECUTION_TIME, e 30 arquivos para upload. Mas, considerando que as imagens podem ser grandes, e a internet no interior não é legal, normalmente não consigo enviar todas as imagens, por estourar o tempo.

O que me recomendam?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Answer (score -1):

Você pode tentar aumentar o tempo de execução via php.ini:

**max_execution_time = 600**

ou no próprio arquivo php

**ini_set('max_execution_time','600');**

Adicione mais memoria por execução, isso pode ajudar:

**ini_set('memory_limit','512M');**

Caso a mudança desse parâmetro de configuração não seja possível, você pode mudar a forma que envia os arquivos.

Em vez de enviar todas as imagens juntas em único SUBMIT você pode através de javascript subir arquivos separadamente.

Assim o usuário vai achar que está enviando tudo de uma vez, mais na verdade ele esta enviando arquivo por arquivo, o que pode reduzir ou eliminar o timeout de execução do script PHP

Comment: Rodrigo, obrigado pela pronta resposta. Analisando as duas situações, a mais certa, porém a mais complicada para mim seria refazer o código, a fim de mudar a forma de envio dos arquivos. Li em um site que é complicado aumentar demais o limite, correndo o risco de prejudicar o desempenho do servidor.

Comment: Concerteza mudar a forma de envio é a opção correta a se fazer, se possível me manda o código do formulário e do PHP para que eu possa te ajudar. Tem algumas formas diferentes de fazer isso posso esclarecer algumas dessas formas com vc.